# Bird Identification: New Delhi, April 2018

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I've looked in [Birds of the Indian Subcontinent](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/birds-of-the-indian-subcontinent-9780198077237?cc=in&lang=en&#) (BNHS version, not Inskipp) and two phone apps and still can't find this, although I am a newbie tourist so am probably making a basic mistake. Seen today, 2018-04-07, 9:00 local time, in a New Delhi urban garden.

[image: Grey birds]

Maybe 25cm long. Uniform grey above, mottled grey below, grey legs with slight orange tinge. Orange-yellow bill, very slim light eye ring. I wondered about a [large grey babbler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_grey_babbler), but all the pictures I can find seem less grey.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're on the right track.  Here's a photo of a Jungle Babbler (*Turdoides striata*).  They are found on the Indian subcontinent.

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_babbler

Comment: I'm no pro at species identification, but being in New Delhi (although I see them everywhere I go), I can pretty much confirm this. +1 for this ;)